# I don't have any helpful flag

Tags: support, flagging

I pose, answer, upvote and edit questions. And yet, look at my profile, no "helpful flag" has ever been awarded to me. Where can I buy one?

Comment: Also be sure that it's the mathematica account and on the site itself when checking - meta has it's own tracking (I did not realize that until I was clearing out profiles).

Answer (score 5):

For a flag to be deemed helpful it must first exist and it seems that you have not raised any [moderator flags](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/improved-flagging/) on posts.  When you cast your first flag the system should, after a processing delay, award you the [Citizen Patrol badge](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/badges/8/citizen-patrol).

Related:

- [What are acceptable reasons for flagging as "Requires Moderator attention"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10848/158428)
- [What are the “spam” and “rude or abusive” (offensive) flags, and how do they work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58032/158428)
- [Why does flag marking as helpful/declined not always correlate with moderator action?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105391/158428)